# Creating a wordcloud generator in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I previously created a very simple Wordcloud generator which I would now like to port to work in an angularjs way following best practices.

This is what I did previously in the jquery project:

I had a variable containing a selectin of text:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit........Suspendisse fermentum venenatis tincidunt.";
```

I then split the text variable into an array of words

```
var word_list = text.split(/\W+/);
```

Below is where I populate my cloud. I randomly allocate the size a word should be with Math.random which then corresponds to a css class which sets the font-size ( class="cloud_' + wordSize + '" )

```
function populateKeywordCloud(wordCount, selector) {
    for (i = 0; i < wordCount ; i++) {
        wordSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        $(selector + ' #keyword_cloud .dataBoxContent').append('<span class="cloud_' + wordSize + '" title="Keyword wordSize ' + wordSize + ' times" ">' + word_list[i] + '</span> ');
    }
}
```

The cloud is initialised in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    populateKeywordCloud(30, '.summary_page');
}
```

So my question is how will I do this in the angularjs way?

Do I create a custom directive and create a link function where I do all my wordcloud logic. A template file called under templateUrl: is then to take the wordcloud data and populate the cloud using ng-repeat

Or do I create a directive that pulls in the keyword data from a wordcloud controller which is in charge of generating the data to be used by the directive?

Comment: I think the best practice to find here is to avoid using jQuery any more and managing to separate service logic from controllers. Please wait a bit until I provide a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks I shall await the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, you should forget about selectors. Instead, think controller elements. For instance, as your tag cloud is dynamic, it should be wrapped as a controller.

```
<div id="keyword_cloud" ng-controller="tagCloudCtrl">
  <div class="dataBoxContent">
    <span ng-repeat="word in words" class="cloud_{{ word.size }}" title="Keyword wordSize {{ word.size }} times">{{ word.text }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the template. Notice the `ngRepeat` directive that lets you iterate over an attribute of the `$scope` of `tagCloudCtrl`. Here, we directly use `{{...}}` to evaluate the word's size and text.

Code-size, we fill up this `words` scope variable:

```
angular.module('tagcloud-app', [])
  .value('WORD_COUNT', 3)
  .service('tagService', function() {
    // Fetch your words here
    return {
      getTags: function() {
        return ['aaaaa', 'bBbb', 'CCC', 'dd'];
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('tagCloudCtrl', ['$scope', 'tagService', 'WORD_COUNT',
    function($scope, tagService, WORD_COUNT) {
      var wordSize, word_list = tagService.getTags();

      // This will make the "words" array visible from associated template
      $scope.words = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; i += 1) {
        $scope.words.push({
          text: word_list[i],
          size: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
        });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Moreover, don't forget to separate logic: as you can see, I made a separate service to fetch tags and to store your word count. This will make your app very dynamic, flexible and reusable.

Check out my [**working example on plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZIx6PeHCFLpG7RwODTz?p=preview).

Note that, as mentionned risto, you can use directives to completely abstract your tag cloud from the rest of your app. Once you will be at ease with regular controllers, check out directives at [AngularJS's](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#!)

Enjoy your AngularJS journey!

Comment: Thanks for showing how to structure my logic without needing to use jquery selectors. 

I think I will combine your answer with Risto's answer and create a directive so that I can easily reuse this wordcloud generator in other projects of mine too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's better to encapsulate as much of your logic as possible, so create a directive with all of your logic inside of it, if you can.

If you feel like it needs a controller, try to package it into a module with it's corresponding directive. Keep it reusable.

Comment: Thanks for the decent advice. I reckon I will go the route of using a directive for the whole process. I doesn't seem like a controller is needed here.